# Given $ a_1 =1 $ and $ a_{n+1}a_n=n+1 $. Prove that: $ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{a_k}\ge 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1) $.

Tags: inequality, induction

Given $ a_1 =1 $ and $ a_{n+1}a_n=n+1 $. Prove that: $ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{a_k}\ge 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1) $.

Since $$\sqrt{n+1}-1 = \sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}), $$ I attempt to prove that $$ 2a_n\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}. $$
But it doesn't hold for some even $n$ (easy to find that $a_n=\frac{n!!}{(n-1)!!}$ and test with $ n = 2, 4, \cdots $).

Another way is to show that $$ \frac{1}{a_n}+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} \geq 2(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n}). $$

This seems to hold with some $ n $ tested, but how to prove that? 
Or maybe the result doesn't hold at all.

Comment: It is worth considering that by the AM-GM inequality $$\frac{1}{a_n}+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\geq \frac{2}{\sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, huge oversight by my side. It turned out to be way simpler than expected :D

Comment: Anyway, the previously outlined method (dealing with odd and even indices separately) proves that the asimptotic behaviour of such a sum is given by $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)\sqrt{n}$$